# How return a value from a SSH connection?

Tags: javascript, ssh, return

I am still new to javascript.
My problem:
I check a folder on a server via ssh. If the folder is empty then I want to return a value (true / 1 / ...). But I just can not get back a value from my function.
It always comes back "undefined" ...

What am I doing wrong?
I already read something about promise / callback, but even these approaches did not work ...
Thank you in advance =)

```
async function CheckIfDirectoryIsNotEmpty() {

  let value;
  let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
  let sftp = new Client();

  sftp.connect({
    host: 'xxxxx',
    port: 'xx',
    username: 'xxxxxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxxxxx'

    }).then(() => {
      return sftp.list('/opt/cm-shared-data/example/')
    }).then((data) => {
      if(data.length == 0){
        value = 0;
      }
      else { value = 1;}
      sftp.end();
      return value;
    });
}
```

Call the method:

```
    async function start() { 


    var a = CheckIfDirectoryIsNotEmpty();

   console.log(a); // "undefined"
```

}

Comment: `CheckIfDirectoryIsNotEmpty` doesn't return anything, so, because you've madeit `async` it will return a promise that will always resolve to `undefined` - what you should do is a) remove the `async` because you never `await` and b) `return sftp.connect ....` - then c) `var a = await CheckIfDirectoryIsNotEmpty();`

Comment: `console.log(a); // "undefined"` - I doubt it - probable comes back with a Promise

Comment: @Bravo Perfect!!  It works!!! thx!!!

Comment: but do you understand where you went wrong? I hope so :p

Comment: Yes! = D Now I understand what I did wrong all the time xD